RTSP 1080p Gstreamer player on Raspberry Pi 4
I am trying to run on a raspberry 4B a RTSP H264 1080p stream.
I first tested the file locally on the Raspberry Pi 4.
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux.video_0 ! queue ! h264analyze! avdec_h264 ! stream synchronizer! waylandsink

And the video looks very good, fluid and fast. The CPU is about 50%.
Then I tried to expose the video on an RTSP server (mediamtx) and I tested from another PC with gst-play-1.0 rtsp://192.168.0.120:8554/stream And also via RTSP everything looks very good.
But if I launch the play rtsp from Raspberry Pi, the video is very slow, it is as if it skips many frames.
I also tried to write the pipeline manually:
gst-launch-1.0 rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.0.120:8554/stream is-live=true ! rtph264depay request-keyframe=true ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! waylandsink sync=false 

But same result.
The CPU always stays around 50%, also the network bandwidth is great between the two systems. I'm using weston.
Any idea on how to optimize?
